# How to get list of dependent views in athena

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have been using view_table_usage in postgres information schema. What is the equivalent function in athena to get list of dependent views.

I tried Show Views and information schema but table_name is defined as view name.